# All my mined coins are going to address 0x000000

Tags: mining

I have an ethereum miner up and going for about 24 hours now. For the first 15 hours or so I saw the following text repeated on the screen (each time updating only the timestamp).

```
23:17:27.282|gpuminer0 workloop 1 #6f9a4b23... #6f9a4b23...
23:17:27.342|gpuminer1 workloop 1 #6f9a4b23... #6f9a4b23...
23:17:27.763|gpuminer2 workloop 1 #6f9a4b23... #6f9a4b23...
23:17:28.120|gpuminer3 workloop 1 #6f9a4b23... #6f9a4b23...
```

However I woke up this morning (so about 15 hours passed total) and the output changed such that only the hash changed to something like this

```
21:52:56.111|gpuminer0 workloop 1 #5e57d24f.. #5e57d24f...
21:52:56.156|gpuminer1 workloop 1 #5e57d24f.. #5e57d24f...
21:52:56.212|gpuminer2 workloop 1 #5e57d24f.. #5e57d24f...
21:52:56.678|gpuminer3 workloop 1 #5e57d24f.. #5e57d24f...
```

I had assumed this meant I mined a block while I slept. However when I went to my account it didn't have any additional ether in it and i could find no signs of any mined blocks on my account. Sadly my scroll buffer is too shallow to scroll back and actually see if I mined a block.

So any ideas? Does the hash update on the output even when you don't mine a block? Or did I mine a block and somehow it didn't make it into my account and got lost due to bad configuration or something?

EDIT

So I finally saw the notification that I did in fact successfully mine a block. The block I mined can be seen here: https://www.etherchain.org/block/960905

What is confusing is apparently the block mined went to miner 0x0000* instead of to my own account. What is even weirder is that I am running the miner as follows:

```
geth --rpc --rpccorsdomain localhost --etherbase '0xblahblahblah'&
ethmine -G
```

and when I go into geth to confirm the coinbase address it is set correctly to my own address. I check using:

```
eth.coinbase
```

So why is it still using the 0x0000 miner?

Comment: It seems you are running Geth from git's unstable branch. Can you tell me which commit you are on just to add some more info to the question? Are you 100% you are supplying a valid address to --etherbase?

Comment: @Maran The etherebase I specify is correct. As for running from git's unstable branch, all i did was install from the ubuntu repository using apt-get using "apt-get install geth" .. perhaps there is a better repository to use than the one specified in the official tutorial?

Comment: @JeffreyPhillipsFreeman: Stop your miner and geth instance. Look at the files in your /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ethereum-ubuntu*  remove the one that says dev, apt-get update, apt-get remove geth, apt-get install geth. Restart your miner and geth instance. "web3.version.client" should prove that you're running 1.3.3 stable.

Comment: @linagee Thank you, your response is 100% valid, but already fixed this doing pretty much exactly that. Again, thank you though for the effort :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I found the solution. In the official tutorial it tells you to include the ethereum-dev repository in Ubuntu to get everything installed. This caused me to install from GIT which apparently had this bug in it (which might be related to the recent transaction bug where all transactions were being sent to 0x00000). The version reported off the current install was 1.4.0-unstable. I had since downgraded back to a stable 1.3.3 and mining appears to be successfully working again.

Comment: Hey Jeffrey, thanks for noticing this. We did a huge refactor in the RPC layer and some bugs slipped through. This is fixed by https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/2189 and should be merged in very soon. Sorry about any issues that this might have caused you.

Comment: @PéterSzilágyi No problem, I'm sure you guys will compensate me with a 1000 ETH for my troubles :) Just joking, thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Did you unlock you account ?

```
--etherbase 0x --unlock 0
```

(or the number of the account you wish to unclock , 0 if it's the first one)

Comment: Nope I'll give that a try. It wasn't mentioned in any of the tutorials or manuals. Are you sure it is required or just guessing?

Comment: It shouldnt really be needed tbh.  What happens when you do : "geth account list" in your CLI ?  geth --etherbase 0xxxxxx --mine should be enought.

Comment: I think this was just a legitimate bug. I was on 1.4.0-unstable (something I just realized. I reverted to 1.3.3 which is stable so hopefully im good now. I guess we will see when I mine my next block. I might wind up making 0x0000000 a very rich non-entity :)

Comment: you can also try geth console then type : web3.eth.coinbase  to check the coin base.  Else type : web3.miner.setEtherbase(web3.eth.accounts[0])

Comment: jayD, this is no answer, rather a comment.